# extract syscall names from strace output

Tags: linux, bash, grep, strace, regex-lookarounds

I use the following command to extract syscall names from strace output:

`strace ls 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | grep -P -o '^[a-z]*(?=\()'`

but this command also includes the **ls output** in the output.
how can I prevent that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but this is a bash programming question. there are numerous such questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: There are also numerous such questions in [unix.se].

Comment: This is just about using bash redirection operators on the command line, not really programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to strace that will help you get what you want:

- `-c` will output a table of all system calls run by the command, together with the number of times they were called and CPU usage.

```
$ strace -c ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 31.07    0.000653          20        32           mmap
  9.94    0.000209          20        10           mprotect
  9.80    0.000206          12        16           read
  8.28    0.000174          15        11           close
  7.61    0.000160          16        10           fstat
  6.90    0.000145          16         9           openat
  2.47    0.000052          17         3         3 ioctl
...
```

- The `-o` option will send strace's output to a file, so it won't get mixed in with your process's output.

The following will run the `ls` command, diverting its output to `/dev/null`, and will send strace's output to an `awk` script to extract the last column:

```
$ strace -o >(awk '$1 ~ /^-----/ { toprint = !toprint; next } { if (toprint) print $NF }') \
  -c ls >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

```
mmap
mprotect
read
close
fstat
openat
ioctl
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution with the help of this link: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047

`strace ls 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -P -o '^[a-z]*(?=\()'`

and a useful variant to count the syscalls:

`strace ls 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -P -o '^[a-z]*(?=\()' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

And a better solution using *Mark Plotnick*'s answer:

`strace -o >(grep -P -o '^[a-z]*(?=\()' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr) ls &>/dev/null`